# weighted moving average with numpy.convolve

Tags: python, math, numpy

I'm writing a moving average function that uses the convolve function in numpy, which should be equivalent to a ([weighted moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)).  When my weights are all equal (as in a simple arithmatic average), it works fine:

```
data = numpy.arange(1,11)
numdays = 5
w = [1.0/numdays]*numdays
numpy.convolve(data,w,'valid')
```

gives

```
array([ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.])
```

However, when I try to use a weighted average

```
w = numpy.cumsum(numpy.ones(numdays,dtype=float),axis=0); w = w/numpy.sum(w)
```

instead of the (for the same data) 3.667,4.667,5.667,6.667,... I expect, I get

```
array([ 2.33333333,  3.33333333,  4.33333333,  5.33333333,  6.33333333,
        7.33333333])
```

If I remove the 'valid' flag, I don't even see the correct values.  I would really like to use convolve for the WMA as well as MA as it makes the code cleaner (same code, different weights) and otherwise I think I'll have to loop through all the data and take slices.

Any ideas about this behavior?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you want is `np.correlate` in a convolution the second argument is inverted basically, so that your expected result would be with `np.convolve(data, w[::-1], 'valid')`.

Comment: thanks I see.  And I also did not know that [::-1] will reverse an array/list.  That is extremely useful information!

Comment: As a mere comment, `np.cumsum(np.ones(numdays,dtype=float),axis=0)` is a very complex way to get `np.arange(numdays)+1.` or `np.np.arange(1., numdays+1.)`.