# Plotting moving average with numpy and csv

Tags: arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot, average

I need help plotting a moving average on top of the data I am already able to plot (see below)

I am trying to make m (my moving average) equal to the length of y (my data) and then within my 'for' loop, I seem to have the right math for my moving average.

What works: plotting x and y

What doesn't work: plotting m on top of x & y and gives me this error

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

My theory: I am setting m to np.arrays = y.shape and then creating my for loop to make m equal to the math set within the loop thus replacing all the 0's to the moving average

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import csv
import math


def graph():
    date, value = np.loadtxt("CL1.csv", delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                         converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%d/%m/%Y')})
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg = 'white')

    plt.plot_date(x=date, y=value, fmt = '-')

    y = value
    m = np.zeros(y.shape)
    for i in range(10, y.shape[0]):
       m[i-10] = y[i-10:1].mean()

    plt.plot_date(x=date, y=value, fmt = '-', color='g')
    plt.plot_date(x=date, y=m, fmt = '-', color='b')

    plt.title('NG1 Chart')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')

    plt.show()

graph ()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here lives in your computation of the moving average -- you just have a couple of off-by-one problems in the indexing !

```
y = value
m = np.zeros(y.shape)
for i in range(10, y.shape[0]):
   m[i-10] = y[i-10:1].mean()
```

Here you've got everything right except for the `:1]`. This tells the interpreter to take a slice starting at whatever `i-10` happens to be, and ending just before `1`. But if `i-10` is larger than `1`, this results in the empty list ! To fix it, just replace `1` with `i`.

Additionally, your range needs to be extended by one at the end. Replace `y.shape[0]` with `y.shape[0]+1`.

#### Alternative

I just thought I'd mention that you can compute the moving average more automatically by using `np.convolve` ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)) :

```
m = np.convolve(y, [1. / 10] * 10, 'same')
```

In this case, `m` will have the same length as `y`, but the moving average values might look strange at the beginning and end. This is because `'same'` effectively causes `y` to be padded with zeros at both ends so that there are enough `y` values to use when computing the convolution.

If you'd prefer to get only moving average values that are computed using values from `y` (and not from additional zero-padding), you can replace `'same'` with `'valid'`. In this case, as Ryan points out, `m` will be shorter than `y` (more precisely, `len(m) == len(y) - len(filter) + 1`), which you can address in your plot by removing the first or last elements of your date array.

Comment: lmjohns3! I really appreciate you pointing that out. I believe that the math is still wrong based on the way the moving average is produced. Ex: my goal is to take an equal average of the past 10 data points to plot its average on the 11th data point, if that makes any sense

Comment: also, I believe the math is wrong because when I see the graph, moving average drops off at the end, as if its calculating the average forward rather than backward

Comment: @user2692787 yes, that's because the convolution is effectively padding your input signal with zeros when the `'same'` argument is used. I've updated the description. Read the docs for more examples and info, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think that lmjohns3 answer is correct, but you have a couple of problems with your moving average function. First of all, there is the indexing problem the lmjohns3 pointed out. Take the following data for example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(10)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Your function gives the following moving average values:

```
In [4]: for i in range(3, a.shape[0]):
   ...:     print a[i-3:i].mean(),
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0
```

The size of this array (7) is too small by one number. The last value in the moving average should be (7+8+9)/3=8. To fix that you could change your function as follows:

```
In [5]: for i in range(3, a.shape[0] + 1):
    ...:     print a[i-3:i].sum()/3,
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

The second problem is that in order to plot two sets of data, the total number of data points needs to be the same. Your function returns a new set of data that is smaller than the original data set. (You maybe didn't notice because you preassigned a zeros array of the same size. Your for loop will always produce an array with a bunch of zeros at the end.)

The convolution function gives you the correct data, but it has two extra values (some at each end) because of the `same` argument, which ensures that the new data array has the same size as the original.

```
In [6]: np.convolve(a, [1./3]*3, 'same')
Out[6]: 
array([ 0.33333333,  1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ,
        5.        ,  6.        ,  7.        ,  8.        ,  5.66666667])
```

As an alternate method, you could vectorize your code by using Numpy's [cumsum function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html).

```
In [7]: (cs[3-1:] - np.append(0,cs[:-3]))/3.
Out[7]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.])
```

(This last one is a modification of the answer in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/moving-average-function-on-numpy-scipy).)

The trick might be that you should drop the first values of your `date` array. For example use the following plotting call, where `n` is the number of points in your average:

```
plt.plot_date(x=date[n-1:], y=m, fmt = '-', color='b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, either I'm going nuts or it actually worked - I compared my chart vs. another chart and it seemed to have worked.

Does this make sense?

```
m = np.zeros(y.shape)
for i in range(10, y.shape[0]):
    m[i-10] = y[i-10:i].mean()
plt.plot_date(x=date, y=m, fmt = '-', color='r')
```