# Rolling sum over an array in Python

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-sum

I am given an array X and I am asked to return another array Y where y[t] = x[t] + x[t-1] and y[0] = 0 **without using a for loop** in Python.

What I can think of is using rolling sum but I am not sure if this is the fastest way since I need to convert x into a dataframe/ a series for rolling to work. Is there a faster way to do that? Thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X).rename(columns={0: 'X'})
df['Y'] = df['X'].rolling(2).sum().fillna(0)
Y = df['Y'].values
```

Comment: "without using a for loop" - but is list comprehension okay?

Comment: This question should probably be on codereview.stackexchange.com ... stackoverflow is not good at providing a "faster" way of doing things in general

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288252/fast-rolling-sum although the only answer there uses numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0] + [c + n for c, n in zip(x, x[1:])]
print(y)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 3, 5, 7]
```

This approach relies on built-in functions, so no need to import an external module such as pandas.

Comment: please complete the answer adding why this is or not a better approach

Comment: its not better ... its also not worse ... for some data sets this might be faster... in others it maybe faster to convert to numpy or pandas ... and use their rolling average methods

Comment: it begs the question though of how a list comprehension is different from a loop (hint ... its not) or for that matter how `.rolling()` is just a loop also.    These stupid "trick" questions that put nonsense restrictions on problems  never really make sense

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for one-liners might not give best performace

```
from toolz.itertoolz import sliding_window
[0]+map(sum,list(sliding_window(2, [1, 2, 3, 4]))) # [0, 3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `numpy`, though that still turns the list into an array.

```
y = x + np.roll(x, 1)
y[0] = 0
```

This is fast, short, fairly transparent and doesn't (explicitly) use a `for` loop.

You could also use `map`, which is pretty much the same as the list comprehension and doesn't require any external libraries.

```
y = 0 + map(lambda (a, b): a+b, zip(x, x[1:]))
```

In Python3 this doesn't work, and instead you would need to write:

```
y = [0] + list(map(lambda a: a[0]+a[1], zip(x, x[1:])))
```

or

```
y = [0] + list(map(sum, zip(x, x[1:])))
```