# Summing elements in a sliding window - NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

There is a numpy way to make a sum each three elements in the interval? For example:

```
import numpy as np
mydata = np.array([4, 2, 3, 8, -6, 10])
```

I would like to get this result:

```
np.array([9, 13, 5, 12])
```

Comment: @Ohumeronen Explaining `conv` might take a while. But added few relevant comments in the post.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for taking the time. I see this function seems to be quite complex but I'll also read some documentation about it. Thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate moving average using NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/how-to-calculate-moving-average-using-numpy)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13728392/52074

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We can use [`np.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) -

```
np.convolve(mydata,np.ones(3,dtype=int),'valid')
```

The basic idea with [`convolution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is that we have a kernel that we slide through the input array and the convolution operation sums the elements multiplied by the kernel elements as the kernel slides through. So, to solve our case for a window size of `3`, we are using a kernel of three `1s` generated with `np.ones(3)`.

Sample run -

```
In [334]: mydata
Out[334]: array([ 4,  2,  3,  8, -6, 10])

In [335]: np.convolve(mydata,np.ones(3,dtype=int),'valid')
Out[335]: array([ 9, 13,  5, 12])
```

Comment: Ah now I understand. Based on the provided data I tried it with np.convolve(mydata,[1,2],'valid') and did not understand why the result is not [8, 8, 19, -4, 14]. But this is the output of np.convolve(mydata,[2,1],'valid'). All clear now :-)

Answer (score 9):

Starting in `Numpy 1.20`, the [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view) provides a way to slide/roll through windows of elements. Windows that you can then individually sum:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

# values = np.array([4, 2, 3, 8, -6, 10])
np.sum(sliding_window_view(values, window_shape = 3), axis = 1)
# array([9, 13, 5, 12])
```

where:

- `window_shape` is the size of the sliding window
- `np.sum(array, axis = 1)` sums sub-arrays

and the intermediate result of the sliding is:

```
sliding_window_view(np.array([4, 2, 3, 8, -6, 10]), window_shape = 3)
# array([[ 4,  2,  3],
#        [ 2,  3,  8],
#        [ 3,  8, -6],
#        [ 8, -6, 10]])
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution without using external libraries might look like this:

```py
from collections import deque

def sliding_window_sum(a, size):
  out     = []
  the_sum = 0
  q       = deque()
  for i in a:
    if len(q)==size:
      the_sum -= q[0]
      q.popleft()
    q.append(i)
    the_sum += i
    if len(q)==size:
      out.append(the_sum)
  return out

v = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
sliding_window_sum(v, 5)
```

Which gives the output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

This matches the result of using numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
np.convolve(v, np.ones(5, dtype=int),'valid').tolist()
```