# Is there the equivalent of matlab's movsum function in python?

Tags: python

[image]Does python has an equivalent function of moving sum? I want to take the maximum value of the variable P1 and then I want to calculate the moving sum using a slide window of 9 elements.

This is my code in MATLAB:

```
SP = movsum(max(P1,0),[9 0]);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not in the built-in libraries. Wouldn't be surprised if `numpy` or `scipy` or the like added it, but it's not a built-in.

Comment: There are several ways which you can find in the dupe - you can adapt the numpy based ones by not dividing by the window size

Comment: @yatu  can you make an example based on my code?

Comment: Well its hard to tell what the output should be, not sure what the role of [9,0] is? Can you post a minimal example and expected output?

Comment: @yatu yes sure. I uploaded a picture. There you can see the input variable P1. I want to identify the position of its maximum values, then i want to repeat the maximum value for 9 positions left. For the other values I want to place it 0 (instead of -2) and store the results in a new matrix called SP. This is working in Matlab but I really don't know how to write it in python

Comment: Please don't upload pictures, post a simple reduced example, and expected output. See this post on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you for the reply. Can you help me?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507672/summing-elements-in-a-sliding-window-numpy) is very close to your question.

Comment: thank you @iamvegan