# Sum elements in window by n step in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, sliding-window

Is a Numpy way to make a sum each three elements in the interval with a step? For example:

```
import numpy as np
mydata = np.array([4, 2, 3, 8, -6, 10])
```

I would like to get this result:

```
np.array([9, 12])
```

I suppose that *np.convole* can do this, according to [Summing elements in a sliding window - NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507672/summing-elements-in-a-sliding-window-numpy), but can I change the step from *n=1* to *n=3*, in this case?

Comment: Try something like `mydata.reshape(-1, 3).sum(axis=1)`. This assume `mydata.size` is divisible by 3. Otherwise you need to pad the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `reshape` (requires the array length to be a multiple of `n`):

```
n = 3

mydata.reshape(-1, n).sum(1)
```

If you don't have a multiple, you can trim:

```
n = 3

mydata[:len(mydata)//n*n].reshape(-1, n).sum(1)
```

Using `convolve`, which should be much less efficient for large `n` as many values (`n-1` out of `n`) are computed for nothing:

```
np.convolve(np.ones(n), mydata)[n-1::n]
```

Output: `array([ 9, 12])`

Comment: All solutions are great! I like the third one, but trimming should not be done. It should be pad with 0 and sum the rest.

Comment: In this case you can use `numpy.pad`