# numpy moving window on 2d array or further more 3d ....nd array

Tags: python, numpy

As we know that moving window on 1d array has answered by Jaime,[moving_average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/how-to-calculate-moving-average-using-numpy)

How can I apply mean function or sum function on 2d array using the moving window?
Like in picture, apply mean function on the red box, and arrow point to result should be.[image]

Comment: I've seen screenshots of data before, but have you just posted an actual photograph of your data?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, Thanks, that's what i want.