# Plotting Moving Average in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, moving-average

I've done some research, but i don't really understand how MA is made. I have this plot:
[image: Without MA]

but I really want something like this:
[image: With MA]

my code is quite simple ( `loss[20:]` is the list from which want I to do the Moving Average):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.plot(acc[20:])
plt.plot(loss[20:])
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(X) + 200, 500))
plt.show()
```

I would really appreciate some explanation about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/how-to-calculate-moving-average-using-numpy?

Comment: @ForceBru yes, it does. Thank you very much