# Running Mean of Circular Data: Average and Standard Deviation?

Tags: python, mean, moving-average

Given such a list:

`mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

with `N = 3` as the size of running mean at each step.

What is the fastest way to calculate the average and standard deviation of this list?

If it was only average `np.convolve` could do the job, but what about the standard deviation? or standard error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np
N=3
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

res=np.vstack([mylist[i:]+mylist[:i] for i in range(N)])

ma=res.mean(axis=0)
std=res.std(axis=0)
```

**Just** for moving average you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14314054/11610186

Comment: This is correct for non-circulat data, what about circular ones? I also need to compute the average for [6,7,1] and [7,1,2]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
double = mylist * 2
N = 3
mean_std = [(np.mean(double[i:i+N]), np.std(double[i:i+N])) for i in range(len(mylist))]
```

Comment: This is correct with not circular data, as it gives only 6 values. How does it work with circular data, i.e. 7 values?

Comment: what do you mean by circular data?

Comment: mylist is circular, meaning that I should also compute the average also for [6,7,1], [7,1,2], getting an average with 7 values

Comment: I modified the solution so that it works for your case