# calculate a rolling average of n length for a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

So I am trying to find a way to calculate a rolling average for n periods in a Numpy Array. I currently have this code where I would like to create a rolling average of lets say 10 periods.

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np

TROW = yf.Ticker("TROW")
price = TROW.history(start='2010-01-01',end='2020-01-01')
arr = np.array(price)`
arr = arr[:, 3]
```

I would like to add a column in `arr` and create the rolling average in the same array. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate moving average using NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/how-to-calculate-moving-average-using-numpy)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/how-to-calculate-moving-average-using-numpy