# how to smooth accuracy and loss curves in deep learning models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

There is an imbalance two class classification problem with 12750 samples for class 0 and 2550 samples for class 1. I've gotten class weights using `class_weight.compute_class_weight` and fed them to `model.fit`. I've tested many loss and optimizer functions. The accuracy on test data is reasonable but loss and accuracy curves aren't normal, which are shown as below. I was wonder if some one give me a suggestion that how can I smooth the curves and fix this problem.
Thank you

[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D,Dropout, Conv1D
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import scipy.io
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
#General Variables
batch_size = 32
epochs = 100
num_classes = 2
#Load Data
# X_p300 = scipy.io.loadmat('D:/P300_challenge/BCI data- code 2005/code2005/p300Cas.mat',variable_names='p300Cas').get('p300Cas')
# X_np300 = scipy.io.loadmat('D:/P300_challenge/BCI data- code 2005/code2005/np300Cas.mat',variable_names='np300Cas').get('np300Cas')
X_p300 = scipy.io.loadmat('/content/drive/MyDrive/p300/p300Cas.mat',variable_names='p300Cas').get('p300Cas')
X_np300 = scipy.io.loadmat('/content/drive/MyDrive/p300/np300Cas.mat',variable_names='np300Cas').get('np300Cas')
X_np300=X_np300[:,:]
X_p300=X_p300[:,:]
X=np.concatenate((X_p300,X_np300))
X = np.expand_dims(X,2)
Y=np.zeros((15300,))
Y[0:2550]=1
#Shuffle data as it is now in order by row colunm index
print('Shuffling...')
X, Y = shuffle(X, Y)
#Split data between 80% Training and 20% Testing
print('Splitting...')
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, Y, train_size=.8, test_size=.2, shuffle=True)
# determine the weight of each class
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                 np.unique(y_train),
                                                 y_train)

class_weights = {i:class_weights[i] for i in range(2)}

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(256,kernel_size=3,activation='relu', input_shape =(1680, 1)))
# model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics= ['acc'])
## use it when you want to apply weight of the classes
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,class_weight=class_weights, validation_split = 0.3, epochs = epochs, verbose = 1)
#model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=32,validation_split = 0.1, epochs = epochs, verbose = 1)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

history_dict = history.history
history_dict.keys()
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values = history_dict['val_loss']
acc = history_dict.get('acc')
epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)
plt.plot(epochs, loss_values, 'r--', label = 'Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss_values, 'b', label = 'Validation_loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

acc_values = history_dict['acc']
val_acc_values =  history_dict['val_acc']
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r--', label = 'Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc_values, 'b', label = 'Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and Validation accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
model.summary()
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print('test_acc:', test_acc)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory/methodology.

Comment: where should i ask this question?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 2):

Just use a moving average if you want to smooth your curve.

```
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628145/6004997
def moving_average(x, w):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones(w), 'valid') / w

plt.plot(epochs, moving_average(val_acc_values, 5), 'b', label = 'Validation acc')
```

Comment: Thank you. but just smoothing is not what was I meant. I mean how can i fix it using machine learning hyperparameter tuning?