# Moving Average Python formulas

Tags: python, graph, formula, average

I'm looking for formulas to make a graph of one stock and its 20 days moving average. I don't have knowledge about moving average so if someone knows it would be wonderful. Thank you

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: Checkout the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14314054/13328553)