# Compute moving average with non-uniform domain

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, rolling-computation, moving-average

[How to calculate rolling / moving average using python + NumPy / SciPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14313510/850781) discusses the situation when the observations are *equally spaced*, i.e., the index is equivalent to an integer range.

In my case, the observations come at arbitrary times and the interval between them can be an arbitrary float. E.g.,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"y":np.random.uniform(size=100)}, index=np.random.uniform(size=100)).sort_index()
```

I want to add a column `yavg` to `df` whose value at a give index value `x0` is

```
sum(df.y[x]*f(x0-x) for x in df.index) / sum(f(x0-x) for x in df.index)
```

for a given function `f`, e.g.,

```
def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x*x)
```

How do I do this with a minimal effort (preferably in pure `numpy`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
index_np_arr = df.index.values
weighted_sum = np.sum(df['y'].values[:, np.newaxis] * f(index_np_arr - index_np_arr[:, np.newaxis]), axis=0)
entire_sum = np.sum(f(index_np_arr[:, np.newaxis] - index_np_arr), axis=0)


df['yavg'] = pd.Series(weighted_sum/entire_sum, index=df.index)
```

Basically:

- `index_np_arr` is the `np.array` of all possible `x0` values;
- `entire_sum` would, get the denominator for all values in the index by repeating the vector n times, where n is the number of indexes and then subtracting for each `x0`. Finally it would sum it all up;
- `weighted_sum` would do almost the same thing except before we sum we would multiply by the y vector.

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x*x)

df = pd.DataFrame({"y":np.random.uniform(size=100)}, index=np.random.uniform(size=100)).sort_index()

index_np_arr = df.index.values
weighted_sum = np.sum(df['y'].values[:, np.newaxis] * f(index_np_arr - index_np_arr[:, np.newaxis]), axis=0)
entire_sum = np.sum(f(index_np_arr[:, np.newaxis] - index_np_arr), axis=0)


df['yavg'] = pd.Series(weighted_sum/entire_sum, index=df.index)
```

Note: This code does have a high memory usage because you will create an array of shape `(n, n)` for computing the sums using vectorized functions, but is probably faster than iterating over all values of `x`.

Comment: this is 2 orders of magnitude faster than the naive version!

Comment: ...but this allocates a 3d table of size `len(df)`: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 22.0 TiB for an array with shape (14454, 14454, 14454) and data type float64`

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77368184/850781)