# Non-uniform domain moving average using sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, convolution, rolling-computation

[Moving average with non-uniform domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75981262/850781) works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def convolve(s, f):
    """Compute the convolution of series S with a universal function F
    (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html).
    This amounts to a moving average of S with weights F based on S.index."""
    index_v = s.index.values
    weight_mx = f(index_v - index_v[:, np.newaxis])
    weighted_sum = np.sum(s.values[:, np.newaxis] * weight_mx, axis=0)
    normalization = np.sum(weight_mx, axis=0)
    return pd.Series(weighted_sum/normalization, index=s.index)

size = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.random.normal(size=size)},
                  index=np.random.exponential(size=size)).sort_index()
def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x*x*30)
df["avg"] = convolve(df.x, f)
plt.scatter(df.index, df.avg, s=1, label="average")
plt.scatter(df.index, df.x, s=1, label="random")
plt.title("Moving Average for random data")
plt.legend()
```

[image: Moving Average for random data]

***However***, this allocates a `O(size^3)` array:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 22.0 TiB for an array with shape (14454, 14454, 14454) and data type float64

## Is it possible to "*sparsify*" the function `convolve`?

Specifically, `f` normally returns non-0 for a fairly narrow band of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
weighted_sum = np.sum(s.values[:, np.newaxis] * weight_mx, axis=0)
```

is equivalent to

```py
weighted_sum = weight_mx @ s.values
```

which is computed without creating the large intermediate array.

##### The proof is in the pudding

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def convolve(s, f):
    """Compute the convolution of series S with a universal function F
    (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html).
    This amounts to a moving average of S with weights F based on S.index."""
    index_v = s.index.values
    weight_mx = f(index_v - index_v[:, np.newaxis])
    weighted_sum = weight_mx @ s.values
    normalization = np.sum(weight_mx, axis=0)
    return pd.Series(weighted_sum/normalization, index=s.index)

size = 20_000 # 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.random.normal(size=size)},
                  index=np.random.exponential(size=size)).sort_index()
def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x*x*30)
df["avg"] = convolve(df.x, f)
plt.scatter(df.index, df.avg, s=1, label="average")
plt.scatter(df.index, df.x, s=1, label="random")
plt.title("Moving Average for random data")
plt.legend()
```